# Открытие .chm-справки в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, chm

В окне находится кнопка, по нажатию на которую необходимо вызывать `.chm` справку.
В обработчике пишу:

```
private void help_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Help.ShowHelp(this, "DrawIt.chm");
}
```

Но выдаёт:

> не удаётся преобразовать из "MainWindow" в "System.Windows.Forms.Control"

В чём моя ошибка?

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/928122/6766879

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Логично, контролы WPF и WinForms не совместимы между собой.

Для открытия CHM в WPF в [этом посте](https://stackoverflow.com/q/928122/6766879) рекомендуют воспользоваться тем, что Windows открывает файлы в ассоциированной с ними программе:

```
Process.Start("DrawIt.chm");
```

Другой способ - передать в ваш метод первым параметром `null`:

```
Help.ShowHelp(null, "DrawIt.chm");
```